# Django - Is_authenticated method works only on one view

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a following problem. In login.html I added `{% If user.is_authenticated %}` and there everything work. I also added this in navbar.html and home.html, but there it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

This is my views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html', {'user': user_panel})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method =='POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'website/register.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        'registered': registered})

def auth_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Konto jest nieaktywne")
        else:
            print ("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'website/login.html', {})
```

basic.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
          <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>
      <body>
        {% include 'website/navbar.html' %}
        {% block body_block %}
        {% endblock %}
      </body>
    </html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'website/basic.html' %}

    {% block body_block %}
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <div class="container-full-bg" style="background-image:url('{% static 'images/website/jumbotron-website.PNG' %}');" height="100%">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background: transparent">
                <div class="container" style="margin-top: 6em"><h1>Agencja Reklamy FUX</h1>
                     <p>Nasza Agencja to firma z ponad dwudziestoletnią tradycją. Zajmujemy się głównie wielkoformatową
                         reklamą zewnętrzną, dającą niemalże nieograniczone możliwości przekazu.</p></div>

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    Hello {{ user.username }}
                {% else %}
                    You are not loggin in
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

navbar.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #363636;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class = "container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding: 0em"><img src="{% static 'images/website/logo.png' %}"></img></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O Firmie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Klienci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praca</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Wyloguj się</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Zaloguj się</a></li>
            {% endif %}

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'website/basic.html' %}
    {% block body_block %}
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 8rem">
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/login/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 80rem">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" size="60" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 80rem">
            <label for="username">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" size="60" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 80rem">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% else %}
            You are logged! {{ user.username }}
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is `user_panel` in the index view?

Comment: Ehh.. I forgot to delete it. Now everything work